# Is there a utility that would allow me to use my GoPro as a webcam / mic?

Tags: windows, device-driver, gopro

I've got a nifty GoPro Hero 3, which I love. Something that I really like about it is the ultra-wide angle capture, and I'd love to be able to use it for Skype calls, Google + hangouts and other video conferencing.

The problem is, Windows doesn't see it as anything but a mass storage device, where I can get ready access to the SD card. However, the camera itself contains an embedded Cherokee web server, which can be used to get the stream from the camera. However, you have to do that over Wifi, it's not something exposed via USB.

I've seen tricks where people use things like the very awesome VLC player to grab the stream over WiFi (a network the camera itself creates), and then push it somewhere else over the wired (Internet) connection. However, this is incredibly complicated to set up, and doesn't help when you want to just use the device as you'd use any other camera / mic combo.

I'm wondering if someone has come up with a sort of virtual driver that connects to the camera over Wifi, and then presents it as a physical device to Windows,  in such a way that you could use it with Skype and similar software?

Or, possibly, something that *would* work with the camera just connected via USB (I'm not certain that's possible, but ..)

My requirements are:

- Able to work with the GoPro Hero 3
- Connects to the GoPro and presents it as if it were a physically connected device
- Has some simple means of letting me put in my GoPro wifi network credentials, if it works over wifi

Nice to have:

- Polished software that installs somewhat easily. I realize this is research-y and I'm *fully* open to something I'd have to build myself (Github / etc)
- Being able to turn the camera on / off as long as Wifi remained on (if via Wifi)

I realize that I need to utilize Wifi only for the GoPro, and be on a wired connection if I went that route.

I'd *really* love to be able to use my GoPro when my daughter chats with her grandparents and such over Skype, I just can't find anything that lets me expose the camera in a way that such programs can use.

Comment: question is one year old, just interesting if you tried something with GoPro, because I see some instructions video on youtube, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhFzrYBXItc and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIAwU6uKaOI

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use a GoPro as a WebCam device. The USB input on the device is used for charging and transferring of files only.

The WiFi is built for the same. My suggestion is to pick up a Logitech Webcam ( http://www.logitech.com/en-us/webcam-communications/webcams ) they are relatively inexpensive and will achieve your video streaming needs. I use them every day at the enterprise level.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this post, I know it's old. You can actually use your gopro as a webcam. You will need a video capture card to achieve that. I have created a step by step guide on how to do this.
You will be able to use it for live streaming and a webcam for Skype and any other IM software. You can check it here: http://actiongadgetsreviews.com/how-to-use-a-gopro-as-a-webcam
Thanks

Comment: URL answers are not accepted here, each answer must be complete without having to click on a link. You can give the URL to your article at the end, but please first give the essential steps here, thanks! :-)

Comment: By the way, answering old questions is perfectly OK, and you have the potential to make a great answer that will be highly upvoted.